# How can I assign a tuple to a dictionary key in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, count, tuples

I have a data like this:

```
(asn,prefix,ip,count_domain)
(15967, '77.55.0.0/16', '77.55.236.177', 10)
(15967, '77.55.0.0/16', '77.55.236.178', 11)
(20773, '195.225.104.0/22', '195.225.104.182', 22)
(20773, '195.225.104.0/22', '195.225.104.181', 10)
(8560, '87.106.0.0/16', '87.106.1.10', 15)
(20454, '198.24.128.0/19', '198.24.143.43', 89)
(20454, '198.24.128.0/19', '198.24.143.45', 608)
(20454, '198.24.128.0/19', '198.24.143.46', 32)
(31815, '216.70.96.0/20', '216.70.102.229', 12)
(31815, '216.70.96.0/20', '216.70.102.228', 20)
```

and I want to extract some of number of ips and domains per asn and prefix, like below:

```
(asn,prefix,count_ip,count_domain)
(15967, '77.55.0.0/16', 2, 21)
(20773, '195.225.104.0/22', 2, 32)
(8560, '87.106.0.0/16', 1, 15)
(20454, '198.24.128.0/19', 3, 729)
(31815, '216.70.96.0/20', 2, 32)
```

my current python script is this but I am getting error for wrong syntax in dictionary. Can anybody help?

```
count = {}

with open (output,'w') as w:
    with open (file , 'r') as f:
        for line in f :
            if line.strip() != '':
                domain = int(line.split('|')[1])
                if  domain>=10:
                    ip = line.split('|')[0]
                    try:
                        prefix = asndb.lookup(ip)[1]
                        asn = asndb.lookup(ip)[0]
                        if [asn,prefix] not in count:
                            count[asn,prefix] = count
                        else:
                            count[asn,prefix] += count
#                        print(asn,prefix,ip,domain)
                    except:
                        print line
                        pass
```

ERROR:

```
    if asn,prefix not in count:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the _exact error_ you're getting, and especially on which line does it occur. I think the `if [asn,prefix] not in count:` is the problem, but that would not give a syntax error. Oh, and: that line probably _is_ giving an error, but your `except:` hides it.

Comment: `[asn,prefix]` is a list, and you cannot search for a list in dictionary as they are not hashable. Use `(asn,prefix)`.

Comment: You're also treating `count` as both a dictionary and something that can be added. Should it be a `collections.Counter`? In general, if asking for help with an error, posting the error helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly assign a tuple with the values of `asn` and `prefix`, and then use the tuple as the key (I think this is what you're trying to do, based on the title).  Also, if you're using the dictionary the way I think you're using it, increment the count by 1 (instead of trying to assign a reference to the dictionary as the value).

```
                    prefix = asndb.lookup(ip)[1]
                    asn = asndb.lookup(ip)[0]
                    key = (asn, prefix)
                    if key not in count:
                        count[key] = 1
                    else:
                        count[key] += 1
```

Edited to fix a silly typo caught by @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: You're right @AshwiniChaudhary - I was trying to preserve as much of OP's code as possible and missed that.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: But you could have mentioned that only immutable types can be used as key!

Comment: @rchang and Ashwini Chaudhary Thanks for your help. Your point was correct I fixed that. But something else that was part of my question is that how can I at the same time, get some of the fourth variable (domain) per key - see my example results

Comment: @pwagner That is certainly a worthwhile point to make - I was giving the OP the benefit of the doubt.  Since OP specifically mentioned "tuple" in the title of the question (and not "list" or something like that), perhaps OP already knows of the differences in mutability between those types.

Comment: @user2058811 The two most straightforward strategies that come to mind are to either 1) store two dictionaries, one for IP count and another to trap the domain counts, or 2) store a single dictionary whose values are two-tuples containing IP counts and domain sums as their elements.  I'd personally recommend approach #1 (using two different dictionaries) - the implementation could be very similar to the IP dictionary, you'd just have to increment by `int(asndb.lookup(ip)[3])` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [asn,prefix] not in count:
```

list type can not be the key of dict.